# How to test component on passing object as props?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

FileUploadStatus.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import FileUploadStatus from './FileUploadStatus';
import { expect, jest } from '@jest/globals';
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json';
import { FileResponse } from '../../constants/mockdata';
describe('Page File upload status component', () => {
  const fn = jest.fn();
  it('Should test File upload status component', () => {
    let props;
    let FileUploadRespData;
    beforeEach(() => {
      FileUploadRespData = {
        uploadResp: { ...FileResponse },
        fileHead: 'IRI File Upload Status:',
      };
    });
    const wrapper = shallow(<FileUploadStatus {...FileUploadRespData} />);
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

mockdata.js

```
export const FileResponse = {
  linesProcessed: 0,
  invalidLineList: [
    {
      lineNumber: 0,
      invalidLine:
        "CSVRecord [comment='null', recordNumber=2, values=[CARR GOTTSTEIN 1834 : 2029 AIRPORT BEACH RD, ALEUTIANS WEST, AK, KELLCO PC PRINGLES - TEST, 12345, 4.912095761, 0.379420315]]",
      invalidLineReason: 'Unknown TD Linx ID (12345)',
    },
  ],
};
```

FileUploadStatus.jsx

```
import { Grid, makeStyles, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import React from 'react';
import '../../../scss/Files.scss';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  marginTop: {
    marginTop: '3%',
  },
});
function FileUploadStatus({ fileHead, uploadResp }) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div>
      <Typography className='typo'> {fileHead}</Typography>
      <br />

      <span className='message'>Null</span>
      <div className='para'>
        <Typography>
          Lines Processed Successfully: {uploadResp.linesProcessed}
        </Typography>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default FileUploadStatus;
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'linesProcessed' of undefined

```
  18 |       <div className='para'>
  19 |         <Typography>
> 20 |           Lines Processed Successfully: {uploadResp.linesProcessed}
     |                                                     ^
  21 |         </Typography>
```

I'm getting above error on snapshot test using jest and enzyme. I tried passing mock data as props directly in the component but couldn't fix.How can we fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `FileUploadRespData` and `beforeEach` outside the `it`:

```
let FileUploadRespData;
beforeEach(() => {
  FileUploadRespData = {
    uploadResp: { ...FileResponse },
    fileHead: 'IRI File Upload Status:',
  };
});

it('Should test File upload status component', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<FileUploadStatus {...FileUploadRespData} />);
  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Bring your object outside the `beforeEach()` function:**

```
describe('Page File upload status component', () => {
  const fn = jest.fn();
  it('Should test File upload status component', () => {
    const FileUploadRespData = {
        uploadResp: { ...FileResponse },
        fileHead: 'IRI File Upload Status:',
      };
    const wrapper = shallow(<FileUploadStatus {...FileUploadRespData} />);
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```